How can I clone the buffer in-place?
How can I clone the buffer to an indirect buffer in the current window? Whenever I try an indirect clone, the buffer ends up in a new window;)

C-h f clone-indirect-buffer says in part:

(clone-indirect-buffer NEWNAME DISPLAY-FLAG &optional NORECORD)
Create an indirect buffer that is a twin copy of the current buffer.
...
DISPLAY-FLAG non-nil means show the new buffer with ‘pop-to-buffer’.
This is always done when called interactively.

C-h f pop-to-buffer says in part :

Display buffer specified by BUFFER-OR-NAME and select its window
...
This uses ‘display-buffer’ as a subroutine.

and C-h f display-buffer says in part:

Display BUFFER-OR-NAME in some window, without selecting it.
To change which window is used, set ‘display-buffer-alist’
to an expression containing one of these "action" functions:>
‘display-buffer-same-window’ -- Use the selected window.
...
For instance:
(setq display-buffer-alist '((".*" display-buffer-at-bottom)))

So you can let-bind display-buffer-alist to an appropriate value involving display-buffer-same-window around the call to clone-indirect-buffer. And that can be done with an around advice:
(defun my/clone-indirect-buffer-to-same-window (orig-fun &rest args)
  (let ((display-buffer-alist '((".*" display-buffer-same-window))))
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'clone-indirect-buffer :around #'my/clone-indirect-buffer-to-same-window)

;;; To remove the advice, do C-x C-e after the closing paren on the next line.
;; (advice-remove 'clone-indirect-buffer #'my/clone-indirect-buffer-to-same-window)


Please check and accept: don't leave questions orphaned.
